# How to get a timestamp from DCR (Digital Court Room) player into a Word processor?

Tags: microsoft-word, autohotkey, timestamp

I'd like to be able to get the current playing time of a file in DCR media player and insert it as a timestamp into a word processor (e.g., Microsoft Word).Therefore, something like a macro button can output `HH:MM:SS` or the player time `HH:MM:SS` at the current cursor position.

Is there any existing way to do this? If DCR Player cannot do that, can it be done for the Windows media player?

DCR (Digital Court Room) player documentation can be [found here](https://www.berriencounty.org/DocumentCenter/View/11433/Instruction-Manual---DPv20_UserGuide-PDF).

Thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 1):

DCR player per the user manual is available at BIS Digital Inc.’s [web site](https://bisdigital.com/dcr/) -- the link in the post is just for the manual. Further, once the DCR player is downloaded, there is no sample or example file available to actually use the player (presumably one using this tool might have a DCR recording from a courtroom proceeding or something like that already).  If there's a link to a DCR file online that could be used to try play something back in the DCR player application, please append it to the original post (or reply in the comments).

Besides that, in answer to the question "can it be done", the answer is quite likely yes, and a program like AutoHotkey could be used to piece together a solution, however there would be some basic programming work required to pull the pieces together.

**Solution Breakdown**

There would be a few parts to create a technical solution:

1. Detecting the playback timestamp in the DCR player
2. Formatting it according to the desired format (`HH:MM:SS`) (assuming that this desired formatting is not the native format the playback time is shown or detected in--hard to tell without a DCR file to play)
3. Typing, copying or pasting the result into Word
4. Assigning all of this to a shortcut key

**Details**

In regards to #1, the DCR player appears to use legacy controls that are easily detectable by AutoHotkey. Since the control names can be detected, the values can almost definitively be read into a program, and this is also likely possible even if the player isn't visible or on top. Control content for these types of controls is often available via the `ControlGetText` command in AutoHotkey.

In regards to #2, reformatting into the desired format (if that's even needed) is likely just a matter of number/string processing to get the playback time in the desired `HH::MM:SS` format. Without being able to preview an actual file, it's difficult to tell which text would be used (i.e., The text that shows up next to 'Time:'? The text that shows up next to 'Position:'?)

In regards to #3, the resulting string could be inserted at the active cursor position in Word using one of a few different methods.

1. Sending it as an input (i.e., like someone typed it)
2. Copying it to the clipboard first, and then sending a command (i.e., `Ctrl+V`) to paste it into Word
3. Other more complicated ways that probably aren't worth mentioning

Out of these options, the first one would be reliable for a short string like this and would minimize complexity. Sending the text directly would also avoid needing to use the clipboard (which would basically need to be cleared in order to copy/paste the text into Word--the old clipboard could also be restored, but that can present complications--easier to send the text as input).

Finally, in regards to #4, once the above functionality is all in place, assigning a shortcut key in AutoHotkey is trivial (and in fact might be the first step to complete during program testing). For this there are plenty of reference examples under the `Hotkeys` topic in the AutoHotkey help.